# Un équivalent « d’expérience trash », imagé, mais sans la connotation d’immoralité

Tags: expressions, demande-de-mot, synonymes

> Trash : se dit d’une tendance esthétique volontairement négligée et
>   privilégiant la provocation d’un gout douteux. (Il est parfois utilisé
>   comme synonyme de glauque)

Trash semble donc avoir une connotation négative dans le sens de « sale, d’un gout douteux, immoral » (signifie poubelle en anglais...).

Connaissez vous un équivalent qui n’aurait pas cette connotation et qui insisterait plutôt sur la dimension de dureté/difficulté de l’expérience ?

*Le contexte : « L’expérience sera trash » (le mot que je recherche doit permettre de résumer : elle serait extrême, difficile, pas franchement agréable, périlleuse, elle en me confronterait à des choses difficiles, elle m'en fera voir des vertes et des pas mûres)*

Trash me plait parce qu’il insiste sur la notion de difficulté, mais sa connotation « sale/immorale » (que je viens de découvrir et qui m'étonne) me gêne.

Comment: L'adjectif "périlleux" qui est dans la description ne convient pas?

Comment: Je ne vois pas vraiment d'immoralité dans trash.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez le mot est aussi utilisé dans des domaines plus adultes, qui donnent cette connotation vulgaire/immorale à *trash*

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez je suis d'accord, je l'ai découvert en lisant la définition française. Si le mot n'a pas forcément une connotation plus immorale que "petite" ou "française" (Gautier devrait comprendre) je peux donc continuer à l'utiliser.

Comment: @Lisa je ne vais pas relever l'insinuation, plutôt t'enjoindre à taper sur google le mot trash, qui relève du language familier et est utilisé en addition sur un mot, pour y ajouter un caractère insultant/vulgaire/sexuel (comme trashtalk par exemple), en anglais familier.

Comment: @GautierC I was teasing you.

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite ça vient d'Antidote (dictionnaire/correcteur)

Comment: Pour résumer, c'est hardos. *(en esperant que ça ne fasse pas trop film porno)*.

Answer (score 7):

Je propose **Rude** - [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rude/70191?q=rude#69432)

> Qui est sévère, brutal
>
> Qui est pénible, exige des efforts soutenus, de la résistance
>
> Qui est difficile à vaincre, redoutable dans les affrontements

Answer (score 5):

Mon préféré :

**Eprouvant** - [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9prouvant/30613?q=%C3%A9prouvant#30527)

> Pénible à supporter, qui met à l'épreuve la résistance physique ou morale.

Autres :

**Pesant** - [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pesant/59870?q=Pesant#59504)

> Qui est pénible à supporter.

**Exigeant** - [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/exigeant/32127?q=Exigeant#32050)

> Qui est difficile à pratiquer, qui impose de gros efforts.

**Ardu** - [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ardu_ardue/5125)

> Qui est difficile à résoudre, pénible à faire.

**Laborieux** - [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/laborieux/45789?q=laborieux#45726)

> Qui coûte beaucoup de travail, d'efforts. Qui se fait difficilement.

L'analogue anglais est typiquement [**challenging**](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/challenging). Malheureusement, bien que **challenge** soit devenu assez commun en français, je ne pense pas que son gérondif soit vraiment utilisable dans un contexte grand public.

A partir de ces synonymes, lequel choisir va principalement dépendre de ce que tu veux dire exactement et du public que tu souhaites toucher. Bonne chance !

Comment: J'ajouterais [**Rude**](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rude/70191?q=rude#69432): _Qui est sévère, brutal_ || _Qui est pénible, exige des efforts soutenus, de la résistance_ || _Qui est difficile à vaincre, redoutable dans les affrontements_. D'ailleurs, j'en fais une réponse.

Comment: "Ardu" me semble être la meilleure proposition. Les deux premières propositions apportent la notion de pénibilité donc je les rejette d'emblée, quant à "Exigeant" il apporte une notion d'élitisme.

Answer (score 3):

S'agissant du contexte "l'expérience sera trash", je suggérerais une recherche incluant la tournure de type "ça va X", qui ouvrent un plus large choix de formules imagées :

**Ça va être chaud**

**Ça va être péchu**

**Ça va pas rigoler**

**Ça va pas être de la rigolade**

**Ça va morfler**

**On va en baver**

Comment: ahaha: "péchu"!